# using Boost.Fusion list of function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion, boost-lambda

I  am trying  to apply list of function object to some value in the following code.
But this code cause 
**err

boost_1_44\boost\fusion\algorithm\iteration\detail\for_each.hpp(82): error C2064:**

How to apply list of function object to some value?

```
double doublef2(double x,double y){return 2*x+y; }
double doublef3(double x,double y){return 3*x*y; }
double doublef4(double x,double y){return 4+x*y; }
main(){
    boost::fusion::vector<
        boost::function<double (double,double)>,
        boost::function<double (double,double)>,
        boost::function<double (double,double)>
       > tt;


    boost::fusion::at_c<0>(tt)= & doublef2;
    boost::fusion::at_c<1>(tt)= & doublef3;
    boost::fusion::at_c<2>(tt)= & doublef4;

boost::fusion::for_each(tt, std::cout << boost::lambda::_1(10,100) << '\n');

}
```

Comment: Well, you left the interesting part of the error message out - the message!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is entirely unrelated to boost.fusion. Rather, your problem is caused by trying to invoke a non-lazy functor from a boost.lambda functor (without using `bind`). Using `boost::fusion::for_each` with a proper functor instead of a boost.lambda functor nets the results you expect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_c.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>

double doublef2(double x, double y) { return 2. * x + y; }
double doublef3(double x, double y) { return 3. * x * y; }
double doublef4(double x, double y) { return 4. + x * y; }

struct proper_functor
{
    typedef void result_type;

    proper_functor(double x, double y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }

    template<typename F>
    void operator ()(F const& f) const { std::cout << f(x_, y_) << '\n'; }

private:
    double x_, y_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::fusion::vector<
        boost::function<double (double, double)>,
        boost::function<double (double, double)>,
        boost::function<double (double, double)>
    > tt;

    boost::fusion::at_c<0>(tt) = doublef2;
    boost::fusion::at_c<1>(tt) = doublef3;
    boost::fusion::at_c<2>(tt) = doublef4;

    boost::fusion::for_each(tt, proper_functor(10., 100.));
}
```

As an aside, it would be quite strange to encounter this usage of boost.fusion in real code; fusion containers are meant for homogeneous types, if you're using all the same type, use `std::array`/`std::tr1::array`/`boost::array` instead and save yourself some compile time.

Answer (score 0):

As *ildjarn* mentioned, applying function call operator `()` directly to
`lambda::placeholders` seems not to work somehow.
Probably `lambda::bind` will meet the purpose in this case.
For example:

```
fusion::for_each(tt, cout << lambda::bind( lambda::_1, 10, 100 ) << '\n')
```

Hope this helps